Are interior-point methods guranteed to converge to the global optimum of a convex objective function?
I am looking into convex optimization. However, I am not sure if there are interior-point methods that are guaranteed to converge to the globally optimal solution given either a strictly convex or a convex optimization objective. Both cases are relevant.
I have read about gradient based convex optimization methods such as sequential quadratic programming that depending on their initialization (and number of iterations) may not neccessarily converge towards the globally optimal solution of a strictly convex or a convex optimization objective. Since this method is closely related to Newtons-methods, which has the same shortcoming regarding convergence.
Therefore my question: Are interior-point methods guranteed to converge to the global optimum of a convex objective function?
Can somebody give me an answer to my question, or maybe point me to the publication, or even the statement in a publication that answers my question?

Generally speaking, if Nocedal and Wright covers the optimization topic that you are interested in, then that's probably where you should start. Check out chapter 19 of their text. https://www.math.uci.edu/~qnie/Publications/NumericalOptimization.pdf

If you dont getan answer here, you find optimization experts over at https://or.stackexchange.com/

Thank you @JohnMadden for your source suggestion.

Thanks to @kjetil b halvorsen for suggesting or.stackexchange. I will ask there as well.
